# Appcelerator - iOS : Animate view's opacity with animate method don't change the opacity property

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Change the view's opacity with animate({}) method don't change the opacity property of the view.

It's normal?

Related ticket on [jira](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4849)

Test code

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: "white"
});
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 100,height : 100,backgroundColor : "red",opacity : 1.0
});
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,top : 30,color : "red",textAlign : "center",font : {fontSize : 20}
});
var buttons = Ti.UI.iOS.createTabbedBar({
    bottom : 30,labels : ["Without animate","With animate"],index : 0,tintColor : "red"
});

var temp = true;
setInterval(function(e){
    if(temp){
        if(buttons.index == 0)
            view.opacity = 0.0;
        else
            view.animate({ opacity : 0.0 , duration : 0});
    }else{
        if(buttons.index == 0)
            view.opacity = 1.0;
        else
            view.animate({ opacity : 1.0 , duration : 0});
    }
    temp = !temp;
    label.text = "view opacity: " + view.opacity;
},200);
win.add(label,view,buttons);
win.open();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Everything is working as expected. All you need to know is little bit more info about how animations work in any platform, be it native Android, iOS or Titanium itself.

Doing animations on a **View, Button**, etc. moves only the **rendered pixels** on the screen of that element, but their properties' values remains same.

So, if you want, then you can set the View's original left value = 10 and then animate it to 100, and you will find that after completion of this animation - the left is still = 10 (not 100).

Therefore, you need to manually set those properties yourself at the end of the animation by passing a callback in **animate()** method.

Do remember that any UI element's properties do have their own getter & setter methods which changes the rendering of the element, but vice-versa is not true.

**Here's your code (little modified) to play with which will give you what you wanted to see.**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: "white"
});
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 100,height : 100,backgroundColor : "red",opacity : 1.0,
    left : 10
});
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,top : 30,color : "red",textAlign : "center",font : {fontSize : 20}
});
var buttons = Ti.UI.iOS.createTabbedBar({
    bottom : 30,labels : ["Without animate","With animate"],index : 0,tintColor : "red"
});

var temp = true;

setTimeout(function () {
    view.animate({
        left : 100,
        duration : 1000
    }, function () {
        view.left = 100;   // commenting this line will give you left = 10
        label.text = "view left: " + view.left;
    });
}, 1000);

win.add(label,view,buttons);
win.open();
```

Comment: thanks, but i know how the animations work (on iOS). I think that this must be the normal working (the change of the property automatically at the end of the animation). Meanwhile the bug has been confirmed.